# Escaping string for SQL in C++

Tags: c++, sql, string, sqlite, escaping

I am searching a simple "addslashes" function for a program that must save in a sqlite database some information.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not bind your string to a prepared statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'd suggest to use **prepared statement** and data binding to query so you would not need escaping or use a library like [CppDB](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/sql/cppdb/) or [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) to do it easily
2. Sqlite3 uses SQL standard quites, so for escaping text you need to "double the quotes" for blob you need hexadecimal representation, i.e.

   ```
   C string: char const *s="I'm" -> SQL: 'I''m'
   C blob  : char s[2]={0xFF,0}  -> SQL: x'FF00'
   ```

   See: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to re-implement addslashes, you should instead look into using prepared statements. They're simpler, faster, and easier.

Comment: prepared statement are, generally speaking, slower. At least in posgres (since you can't preplan the query with table statistics) see http://goo.gl/63QcR for an explanation and an example.

Comment: I stand corrected, then. But they're still simpler and easier and better.

Answer (score -5):

I think its `echo " \\hi  ";`
- ouput \hi